# Usage of bucketfullaccesscontrol permission in bucket objects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I am using spring integration channel technology in my application. I just want to put some files inside aws s3 bucket with full access permissions. my  configuration is in XML form.

Need to implement via using expression-acl-object attribute  in s3 outbound gateway .

Please help to configure this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear and it is fully out of our imagination what is your code without any samples from your side. But still it sounds like you are talking about:

```
    <xsd:attribute name="object-acl-expression">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                A SpEL expression to evaluate S3Object ACL at runtime against request message
                for the 'upload' operation.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

The result of this expression must be an instance of `AccessControlList` or `CannedAccessControlList`:

```
Object acl = this.objectAclExpression.getValue(this.evaluationContext, requestMessage);
Assert.state(acl instanceof AccessControlList || acl instanceof CannedAccessControlList,
                    "The 'objectAclExpression' ["
                            + this.objectAclExpression.getExpressionString()
                            + "] must evaluate to com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AccessControlList " +
                            "or must evaluate to com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList. " +
                            "Gotten: [" + acl + "]");
```

So, if you talk about a *full access permissions*, it looks like you just need to use `CannedAccessControlList.AwsExecRead` in that expression:

```
/**
 * Specifies the owner is granted {@link Permission#FullControl}. Amazon EC2
 * is granted {@link Permission#Read} access to GET an Amazon Machine Image
 * (AMI) bundle from Amazon S3.
 */
AwsExecRead("aws-exec-read");
```

Such an expression may look like:

```
object-acl-expression="T(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList).AwsExecRead"
```

Comment: I was looking for the last line which you mentioned above. Thanks a lot